# Prove that if one of the numbers $(2^n)-1$, $(2^n)+1$ is prime, then the other is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let n be an integer greater than 1. Prove that if one of the numbers
$$2^n-1, 2^n+1$$ is prime, then other is composite.

Comment: What about $n=2$? Both 3 and 5 are primes.

Answer (score 10):

One of $2^n-1,2^n,2^n+1$ must be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: [Twin primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) greater than $5$ must be of the form $6m\pm 1$ for some integer $m$.

Answer (score 1):

If both are primes,
$$2^n\pm1=6k\pm1,$$
where $k$ is a positive integer. But obviously, $6\nmid2^n$, so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime. If $2^n+1$ is prime, then $n$ is a power of $2$. If $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ are both primes, then $n$ is both a prime and a power of $2$, i.e., $n=2$. Hence $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ cannot both be primes if $n\gt2$. (Of course, if $n=2$, then $2^n-1=3$ and $2^n+1=5$ are both primes, as pointed out in a comment by Martin Sleziak.)